# Why does iodine trichloride dimerize?

Tags: bond, ionic-compounds

> In which of the dimerization process, the achievement of the octet is not the driving force
>
> 1. $\ce{2AlCl3 \to Al2Cl6}$
> 2. $\ce{BeCl2 \to BeCl2}$ (solid)
> 3. $\ce{2ICl3 \to I2Cl6} $
> 4. $\ce{2NO2 \to N2O4}$
>
> Answer: (3) $\ce{2ICl3 \to I2Cl6} $

The answer was given without explanation from the problem book I was solving, so I ask then, what exactly is the reason that $\ce{ICl3}$ dimerize?

From this [website](https://www.mvorganizing.org/what-is-the-lewis-structure-of-icl3/#Why_does_ICl3_exist_as_dimer) , I find it is because it is odd electron and wants to complete the octet, but the question asks why it dimerizes disregarding that rule.

[Related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40211/how-to-rationalise-the-planar-structre-of-i2cl6)

Comment: Your own reasoning – based on searching, reading and thinking – is supposed to be present to avoid the question closure for lack of own explicit  effort.  [How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). // Why not to analyze, where reaching the octet is and is not achieved ?

Comment: I understood what you said now, the thing is they specifically asked which one is not driven by octet rule/ odd electron atom rule

Comment: P.S.: Note that I was refering just to the partial question, if reaching octet is the case or not. I was not referring to the second part what is the cause if it is not.

Comment: It's a dreadful question. Achievement of an octet is never the driving force. The driving force is that dimerisation leads to a lower free energy. Achievement of an octet is merely a hand-waving rationalisation of that observation, it is not the cause.

Comment: @Ianbush It may be perhaps said that at lower periods, reaching minimal energy as the driving force  is often accompanied with completing octet octets. So the latter is merely an indicator, not fully reliable.

Comment: The real difference is that the others dimerize/polymerize to form more bonds, whereas ICl3 dimerizes (which, by the way, is true) to strengthen its existing bonds (2c-2e -> 3c-4e).

Comment: I was thinking similar in dimer no. of bonds increases as a whole.

Comment: In Icl3, the lone pairs are at an 120° angle. It dimerises such that the lone pairs are then at an angle of 180° which causes less repulsion and brings more stability